# My quiz function checks the answer correctly only for the first question. How do I make it work for the next questions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, dom, addeventlistener

So I'm on quiz project that I got assigned in my bootcamp and I'm currently working on a function checkAnswer that check the answer selected by the player.

```
const startButton = document.querySelector(".start") as HTMLButtonElement;
startButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const presentation = document.querySelector(
    ".presentation"
  ) as HTMLDivElement;
  presentation.style.display = "none";
  questionContainer.style.display = "flex";
  displayQuestion(questions[currentQuestion]);
  console.log("je marche");
  checkAnswer(questions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer);
});

function checkAnswer(correctAnswer: string) {
  buttonListener(button1, correctAnswer);
  buttonListener(button2, correctAnswer);
  buttonListener(button3, correctAnswer);
  buttonListener(button4, correctAnswer);
}

function buttonListener(button: HTMLButtonElement, correctAnswer: string) {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (button.textContent === correctAnswer) {
      console.log(`${button.textContent} is the right answer`);
      score += 10;
      currentQuestion++;
      button.textContent = "";
      console.log(
        `The current score is ${score} and the next question is number ${
          currentQuestion + 1
        }`
      );
      displayQuestion(questions[currentQuestion]);
      console.log(currentQuestion);
    } else if (button.textContent !== correctAnswer) {
      console.log(`${button.textContent} is not the right answer`);
      score -= 5;
      currentQuestion++;
      button.textContent = "";
      console.log(
        `The current score is ${score} and the next question is number ${
          currentQuestion + 1
        }`
      );
      displayQuestion(questions[currentQuestion]);
      console.log(currentQuestion);
    }
  });
}
```

[Here is a link to my repo if you want to check the entire code](https://github.com/OrhanMA/Simplon-Quiz/tree/main/src)

Current situation:

- When I click on one of the buttons to select the answer, it displays the next question automatically. That's the behaviour I want it to have: perfect.
- When I select an answer in the first question, the function makes the right comparaison with the button I clicked and tells me in the console if I selected the right one. But when the second question is displayed, when I select the right answer, it's interpreted as false. And that's the same problem for every other questions.

What I think the problem is:
When the second question is displayed, the correct answer isn't changed changed so it keeps comparing the user's selection with the first's question correct answer. That's confirmed by the fact that when I change one of the second question answers by the first's question correct answer, the function now log that it's the correct answer.

What I tried:
I tried to change the correct answer by creating a variable in the displayQuestion function but it's not working.
I also tried the same thing in the checkAnswer function but it's not working either.

I'm just looking for a hint on how to fix that problem. Please don't give me the solution, I just want a hint to put me back on the right track.

Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a click eventListener to your start button and when you pass correctAnswer through initially, you're stuck with that as the correct answer.  You need to have a click event listener on each of the buttons and have a way to cycle through the correctAnswer(s) within your questions object, and then compare them with the textContent of the selected button.  There are multiple ways you could do this - I suggest looking at [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), and the different [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Just be aware that the issue stems from correctAnswer only being passed when startButton is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I debugged myself a hours and saw what the problem was with the checkAnswer function. I added event listeners to each buttons using a for loop and made sure that the correctAnswer gets updated each time I clicked on a button by reassigning the variable value after the check has been made for each questions.